# Bug in Z3 Datalog

Tags: z3, datalog

For the datalog program in Z3 at the bottom, the result of query

```
(query (CallGraph invo heap):print-answer true)
```

given by Z3 is:

```
sat
(and (= (:var 0) #b011) (= (:var 1) #b1))
```

However, the answer should be

```
    sat
     (and (= (:var 0) #b1) (= (:var 1) #b011))
```

am I right? is it a bug in Z3?

```
  (set-option :fixedpoint.engine datalog)
    (declare-rel VarPointsTo ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 3)))
    (declare-rel Reachable ( (_ BitVec 3)))
    (declare-rel Alloc ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 3) (_ BitVec 3)))
    (declare-rel Move ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel FldPointsTo ( (_ BitVec 3) (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 3)))
    (declare-rel Store ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel StrMap ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 1)))
    (declare-rel Load ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel VCall ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 3)))
    (declare-rel CallGraph ( (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 3)))
    (declare-rel InterProcAssign ( (_ BitVec 4) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel FormalArg ( (_ BitVec 3) (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel ActualArg ( (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel FormalReturn ( (_ BitVec 3) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-rel ActualReturn ( (_ BitVec 1) (_ BitVec 4)))
    (declare-var var (_ BitVec 4))
    (declare-var heap (_ BitVec 3))
    (declare-var methHeap (_ BitVec 3))
    (declare-var to (_ BitVec 4))
    (declare-var from (_ BitVec 4))
    (declare-var baseH (_ BitVec 3))
    (declare-var fld (_ BitVec 1))
    (declare-var base (_ BitVec 4))
    (declare-var toMethHeap (_ BitVec 3))
    (declare-var invo (_ BitVec 1))
    (declare-var inMethHeap (_ BitVec 3))
    (declare-var n (_ BitVec 1))

    (rule (=> (and (Reachable methHeap) (Alloc var  heap  methHeap) )(VarPointsTo var  heap)))
    (rule (=> (and (Move to  from) (VarPointsTo from  heap) )(VarPointsTo to  heap)))
    (rule (=> (and (Store base  var  from) (and (VarPointsTo from  heap) (and (VarPointsTo base  baseH) (StrMap var  fld) )))(FldPointsTo baseH  fld  heap)))
    (rule (=> (and (Load to  var  base) (and (VarPointsTo base  baseH) (and (FldPointsTo baseH  fld  heap) (StrMap var  fld) )))(VarPointsTo to  heap)))
    (rule (=> (and (VCall var  invo  inMethHeap) (and (Reachable inMethHeap) (VarPointsTo var  toMethHeap) ))(Reachable toMethHeap)))
    (rule (=> (and (VCall var  invo  inMethHeap) (and (Reachable inMethHeap) (VarPointsTo var  toMethHeap) ))(CallGraph invo  toMethHeap)))
    (rule (=> (and (CallGraph invo  methHeap) (and (FormalArg methHeap  n  to) (ActualArg invo  n  from) ))(InterProcAssign to  from)))
    (rule (=> (and (CallGraph invo  methHeap) (and (FormalReturn methHeap  from) (ActualReturn invo  to) ))(InterProcAssign to  from)))
    (rule (=> (and (InterProcAssign to  from) (VarPointsTo from  heap) )(VarPointsTo to  heap)))
    (rule (Alloc #b0001  #b001  #b010))
    (rule (Alloc #b0010  #b001  #b010))
    (rule (Reachable #b001))
    (rule (Reachable #b010))
    (rule (Alloc #b0011  #b011  #b001))
    (rule (Alloc #b0100  #b100  #b011))
    (rule (Move #b0101  #b0100))
    (rule (StrMap #b0110  #b1))
    (rule (Store #b0001  #b0110  #b0011))
    (rule (StrMap #b0111  #b1))
    (rule (Load #b1000  #b0111  #b0001))
    (rule (VCall #b1000  #b1  #b001))
    (rule (ActualReturn #b1  #b1001))

    (query (VarPointsTo var heap):print-answer true)
    (query (CallGraph invo heap):print-answer true)
    (query (Reachable heap):print-answer true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to reproduce in the version of Z3 checked into GitHub/z3prover/z3 master branch. 
The way the engine associates variable indices with variable names has been brittle and there might still be a way to trigger this bug with the newest version of Z3, although I cannot reproduce it.

The binary API exposes a more reliable API: one poses a query given one or more predicate declarations (The function from the C API is called Z3_fixedpoint_query_relations, and the other supported programming languages support similarly named functions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I use "z3-4.3.2" version to run the smt2 file, and this problems occur in several query relations.